# Disable push notifications from a non-HTTPS website on Firefox Mobile

Tags: notifications, firefox-for-android

I visited a YouTube proxy website, NSFWYouTube, and since then I receive unwanted push notifications from that site like this:

[image above, not showing for me, is https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV11T.png]

There doesn't appear to be a way to disable it in Firefox Mobile 65.0.1 -- the [Mozilla's Support site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-notifications-firefox-android) says to go to the site, click the "lock" icon and disable notifications there. But there is no notification option when I try; the site is not an HTTPS site (not sure if that's why).

I do not recall accepting notifications, is it possible the site click-jacked me into doing so? How can I disable these notifications?

Edit: Additional info, https://pastebin.com/L70PQHnE has copies of some of the JavaScript used on the nsfwyoutube site when spoofing a mobile device, it appears to used "siteswithcontent.com" (which this [Ublock filter list associates with annoying push notifications](https://github.com/PolishFiltersTeam/PolishAnnoyanceFilters/blob/master/PAF_push.txt)) and ultimately [firebase-messaging-sw.js](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/50fb88abb0950a70799207d4da8eae45a4a66d02/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js#L15-L29) to perform the push notifications ... which continue to come through.